# Replace key-value pair in an object with Google Apps Script

Tags: object, google-apps-script

I am making a call to an API for a commercial product using `Apps Script`. Unfortunately, the resulting object has several `key-value` pairs that contain the `id` from a linked table.

I can easily get the standard values and have written code to find the related `name` value and add it to the object. I would prefer to add the `name` in the same location as the original `id`. But, when I add a new `key`, it is added to the end of the object.

I want the `name` in the same location as `id` so when I insert it into a sheet, the columns will still be in order.

This is my object:

```
var json = {id: 4730183,name: "A A", customer_source_id:123, company: "NE Company"};
```

This is my desired object after replacing the `id` with the `name`:

```
var json = {id: 4730183,name: "A A", source:"CRM", company: "NE Company"};
```

Basically, I want to find `customer_source_id` in the object and replace it with `source`.

I can't use `indexOf` and `splice` because the object is not an array.

What is the best way to do this? Do I have to convert it to an array first and then back again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is efficient, but you can iterate through the keys and build a new json object like this:

```
var newjson = {};
for(var key in json){
    if(key === 'customer_source_id'){
       newjson.source = [NEW VALUE TO DISPLAY];
    }else{
       newjson[key] = json[key];
    }
}
json = newjson;
```

But, like @Waqar and @Spencer said, the object is not used for ordered data.

Answer (score 2):

A quick answer would be:

```
   var obj = {id: 4730183,name: "A A", customer_source_id:123, company: "NE Company"};
   var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
   json = json.replace("customer_source_id","source")
```

The better answer is:
@Waqar Ahmed is correct. JavaScript objects are unordered. In your example "var json" is an object not JSON. You can make it JSON with `JSON.stringify(json)`.  But once the JSON is parsed into an object it again becomes unordered. You should not use it to store ordered data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do his only in java script array. Not in JSON. JSON is meant to be addressed by keys, not by index.Change your json to

```
var json ={id: 4730183,name: "A A", customer_source_id:null, items : [] company: "ESI"};
```

Now you can insert items using `push` method of array.

```
json.items.push('My Item');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I re-phrased the question because I don't think my situation was properly explained.